# Regular Expression to match string greater than length, but excluding match at end

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

As the title states, I'm looking for a regular expression that will match a string greater than a given length, so:

```
[\s\S]{51,}
```

So the following would match:

```
Cras risus ipsum, faucibus ut, ullamcorper id, varius ac, leo.
```

And the following would not:

```
Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero.
```

However, I want an additional condition that a particular sequence of characters appearing at the end of the string should be excluded from the character count. That sequence itself could be defined by a regular expression. E.g.:

```
something\/[\w]+\/at-the-end\/[\d]+$
```

So the following should still match:

```
Cras risus ipsum, faucibus ut, ullamcorper id, varius ac, leo.
```

And the following should still not:

```
Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. something/random/at-the-end/12345
```

I'm thinking that if it's possible at all it involves lookarounds in some way, but I don't know how I would go about constructing it. I'm looking for a solution using a single regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using a negative lookahead to temper your pattern match:

```
^((?!at-the-end\/\d+)[\s\S]){51,}[\s\S]*$
```

### Demo

The basic idea behind the pattern is that it will consume any single character so long as what follows is *not* `at-the-end/`, followed by one or more digit, followed by the end of the string.

Comment: That's actually very close, but I was hoping to still make a match if the part before the `at-the-end/123` is greater than the specified length (51 characters in this example). If that's not possible I could work with this solution though.

Comment: @Peter I think I have it fixed now.

Comment: Brilliant! That does indeed work exactly as I'd hoped. In all my trying I had the lookahead on the wrong side.

Answer (score 1):

Not pretty, but this regex works even in javascript :

```
^(.{51,}(?:something\/[\w]+\/at-the-end\/[\d]+$))|((?!.*something\/[\w]+\/at-the-end\/[\d]+$).{51,})$
```

It looks for a line that ends with the random stuff, that's proceeded by at least 51 characters.
Or it looks for at least 51 characters, but without the random stuff at the end.

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/VgfQOw/1)

With the PCRE regex engine you use a pre-defined pattern for that random stuff.

```
(?(DEFINE)(?<random>something\/[\w]+\/at-the-end\/[\d]+$))^(.{51,}(?P>random))|((?!.*(?P>random)).{51,})$
```

Comment: Fortunately the regex engine I'm using supports lookarounds, but it's good to have a non-lookaround version as reference for Javascript, etc. Thanks!

Comment: @Peter It does have a lookahead in the second part, a negative one. But javascript supports the lookaheads.  And soon also lookbehinds, once the major browsers support that new ECMAscript standard.

Comment: Without lookaheads, probably the only way to achieve this is to test for at least 51 characters. Then check if it ends with the random stuff, and test how many characters remain if that random stuff gets removed from the end. And I wouldn't even use a regex to check the length of the string.

Comment: Ah yes, so it does. Testing Tim's solution in javascript it also appears to work.

Comment: @Peter Just a side-note. I used `.` instead of `[\s\S]`. Because it made it easier to test with the multiline flag in the tester. If you search with the single line flag it will test the whole text instead of the lines.